# Remove unwanted spaces from values retrieved from sql database

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple search form that requires the user to provide a name and some other info and it will look for the entry it in the sql database I have. I have problem however when comparing the name field, since the saved names in the sql have some spaces before and after the name, and thus the comparasions fail. How can I remove the spaces from the "RETRIEVED" name? This is the piece of code I use to save the name in the array. 
I want to remove the spaces from within the php code, not directly form the database.

```
$query = 'SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName from student WHERE';
$query_parts = array();         

if($_GET['First_Name'] != "")
    array_push($query_parts, ' FirstName="'.$_GET['First_Name'].'"');


if($_GET['Gender'] != "")
    array_push($query_parts, ' Gender="'.$_GET['Gender'].'"');
```

Comment: how this code compares with your description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use the sql name use the trim function. Example:

```
where TRIM(sqlname) like "$phpVar";
```

Answer (score 0):

Databases provide `trim` function to remove leading and trailing white spaces from the queried values. If you have already queried without trimming you can trim them after you get the results from the database using the `string.trim` function available in the language you are using.

If you want to trim in the sql query you have to write your where clause to use database provided trim function to trim the column on the fly. However, be aware that it can be slower because of on the fly trimming and possible full table scans.